# TinyMCE showing garbage characters whenever page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce-4

I don't know why but whenever the page gets refreshed ( when I select a dropdown, when I click on save button which shows error that some fields need to be filled before submitting the form... in these situation the page gets reloaded)

And whenever page gets refreshed My TinyMCE turns HTML controls visible, and on second refresh it turns those html to garbage character..

**after first refresh**

```
Hi This is john<sup>123</sup>
```

**after second refresh**

```
Hi This is john&lt;sup&gt;123&lt;/sup&gt;
```

Any help ?

Is there a way that I can do partial refresh so that TinyMCE doesn't gets refreshed.

Comment: What sorts of garbage characters? can you include an example in your question.

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't garbage characters. They're URLEncoded. `&gt` is for "greater than" `<`, `&lt` is for "less than" `>`.

TinyMCE is correctly encoding the characters so they can be sent as HTTP payloads. You simply need to decode them and the output will be back to their original ascii characters.

if that's not an option, you can disable encoding on TinyMCE when you initialize it:

```
tinyMCE.init({
     entity_encoding: "raw", // <-- disable encoding
     // ...other settings
}
```

Here is the documentation on [TinyMCE Encoding](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:encoding).

Comment: Hey , so I am using encoding : "xml" in my tinyMCE, and it's working fine..but whenever the page gets refreshed then only it converts it into URLEncoded characters.. not able to fix that problem.

Comment: I also tied to use entity_encoding : "raw" but in the documentation it says that All characters will be stored in non-entity form except these XML default entities: &amp; &lt; &gt; &quot;  http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding